# undefined variable when trying to make sending mail function laravel become reusable

Tags: php, laravel-6

i'm using laravel 6. have several controllers that using Mail function. I want to make a function that will bring mail function in laravel reusable through many controllers so i can call it everywhere just by

```php
Utils::sendGmail($param, $param2)
```

or

```php
Utils->sendGmail($param, $param2)
```

this is what i've done so far(also by googling several keywords that maybe related to my case):

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Mail;
class Utils {
    public function sendGmail($email, $data, $subject, $msgBlade) {
        global $myemail;
        $myemail = $email;
        $data = $data;
        $subject = $subject;
        $msgBlade = $msgBlade;
        Mail::send($msgBlade, $data, function($send) use ($data){
            $send->to($myemail)->subject($subject);
        });
    }
}
```

but return following error:

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable: myemail
```

can you tell me how to solve this problem? thank you.

Comment: `$myemail` is not defined in anonymous function scope `use ($data, $myemail)`.. probably should get same notice/error about `$subject`

Answer (score 1):

`$myemail` is outside the scope of the anonymous function. We have to pass `$myemail` and also `$subject` in the function.
(https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
Mail::send($msgBlade, $data, function($send) use ($data, $myemail, $subject) {
  $send->to($myemail)->subject($subject);
});
```